# pymysql.err.OperationalError) (2013, 'Lost connection to MySQL server during query') (Background on this error at: https://sqlalche.me/e/20/e3q8)

Tags: mysql, sqlalchemy, pymysql

I have isolation_level as AUTOCOMMIT in the engine level cause without it, I was not able to run the SET query I have mentioned below.


I am very new SQLAlchemy and don't know why it uses transaction everywhere. but as I have to run the SET query, it is only working this way only but fails whenever I try to fetch data for anything.

```
import os

from dotenv import load_dotenv
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, event, text
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

load_dotenv()


class DB:
    def __init__(self, db_name, db_username, db_password, db_host, db_port, read_consistency='off'):
        # create engine and session
        self.engine = create_engine(f"mysql+pymysql://{db_username}:{db_password}@{db_host}:{db_port}/{db_name}"
                                    , isolation_level='AUTOCOMMIT')

        self.read_consistency = read_consistency
        self.session = Session(self.engine)

        connection = self.engine.connect()
        app_env = os.getenv('APP_ENV', 'local')
        if app_env != 'local':
            if self.read_consistency == 'on':
                query = text("SET aurora_replica_read_consistency = 'session';")
                connection.execute(query)

        
        # generate models
        self.Base = automap_base()
        self.Base.prepare(self.engine, reflect=True)
        self.generate_models()

    def __del__(self):
        self.session.close()
        self.engine.dispose()

    def get_session(self):
        return self.session

    def generate_models(self):
        tables = self.Base.classes
        for table_name in tables.keys():
            table_class = tables[table_name]
            setattr(DB, table_name, table_class)
```

I tried multiple configuration of sqlAlechemy, to set that query but this was one that worked. but I was expecting it to work properly so that I can perform db operations successfully